# Running multiple instances of WebDriver Test on Sandbox paypal environment results in Session time out issue

Tags: session, selenium, paypal

We are running multiple instances of WebDriver tests which will log in to payPal Sandbox environment, Pay amount and get back to our application.
But this results in Session time out issue.

Error message:
'Your session has timed out, please log in again.'

We want to understand the core reason for this issue.

1. Is this issue happening because we are using the same account in multiple instances? Will this be fixed if we use different paypal accounts?
2. what is the ttl (time to live) for session key generated for a paypal account in sandbox?

Answer (score 1):

This might happen because you might be using same login details . Firefox browsers sometimes shares session. so once a thred logs out other also. Try with different login details

Comment: Yes: it's highly likely that PayPal isn't kosher with the same account credentials opening many sessions at the same time and paying from all those sessions simultaneously. I wonder why...? :-)